# OCMOCK iOS how to test if property is called?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, mocking

I use [OCMOCK](http://ocmock.org/) to build unit test for my plugin.

I have Singleton class `MyClass` with some property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=setUserID:) NSString *userID;
```

I want to validate if `[MyClass shared].userID` is called.

Im able to run unit testing for setter a.e. `setUserID`.

```
id myClassMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyClass shared]];

OCMExpect([myClassMock setUserID:[OCMArg isNotNil]]);

[[MyClass shared] setUserID:@"someUserId"];

OCMVerifyAll(myClassMock);
myClassMock = nil;
```

But how can I test for property `userID`?

In real code I set this properly as:

```
[MyClass shared].userID = @"some id";
```

Thanks,